# Who has the winning hand in Texas-holdem (different full house hands)

Tags: poker-texas-holdem

The table cards were Q,Q,9,9,4

All four suits were on the board.

Player one had Q,3.

Player two had 9,8.

Which player wins?

Answer (score 25):

QQQ99 wins over QQ999, so Player 1 gets it.

When comparing two full-houses, the higher triple wins; if both players have the same triple then the higher pair wins. If both players have the same triple and the same pair, then they split the pot.

---

Note that all suits are equal in Poker - the ranking of suits from games such as [Bridge](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bridge) and Five Hundred have no bearing on evaluating Poker hands.

Comment: So many short explanations of poker hands leave out details like this.

Comment: @Sparr This is such a big thing I wouldn't call it a detail. Knowing if you have the best hand must be considered quite basic and mandatory for explaining anything about the game. Guides omitting stuff like this isn't half decent.

Comment: @AndSoYouCode A lot of people are introduced to poker only by learning the ranks of the different hands. I've seen multi-page rule sets and introductions that don't get into how to differentiate between different full houses.

Comment: @Sparr We'll, that makes me sad... Good thing we have boardgames at stackexchange!